# Behind two DHCP routers: referring/accessing to a computer directly over the Internet

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I've been working on a networked game in C#/XNA lately and the networking itself went pretty well while we had only Static IPs involved. Now the situation is:

My PC is behind a home router (which I have full control of and uses DHCP), and this router/subnet is behind a (probably) company router, because I'm getting my WAN IP through DHCP.

How am I supposed to refer/access my computer over the Internet?
Let's say, using the UdpClient.Send() function (which takes only an IPAddress and a Port as an IPEndpoint next to the data)?
Or is this not even possible and I have to make a virtual network to be able to refer to the computers directly?

(Using the dhcp-d WAN address yields no success, and I have absolutely zero control over the company's router.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can reach (e.g. ping) your home router on the external IP and:

1. if you use NAT then you want to enable port forwarding on the router to the IP of your PC. You might want to give the PC a static IP for this. Or make an entry in the DHCPd for its MAC address so it always get the same IP when it does a DHCP request.
2. If you have your own IP ranger at home then no NAT is needed and you should just be able to reach the PC **unless** you have a firewall configured to block access.

As for the company router. That one should not matter. As long as you can reach a random PC on the internet then it should also work for your home network.

Comment: Thank you Hennes, I realized I had some wrong configuration in forwarding. The pc is completely accessible by it's WAN ip (which is strange as it wasn't 2 months ago). Solved!